# In a DAG, how to find vertices where paths converge?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a type of directed acyclic graph, with some constraints.

1. There is only one "entry" vertex
2. There can be multiple leaf vertices
3. Once a path splits, anything under that path cannot reach into the other path (this will become clearer with some examples below)
4. There can be any number of "split" vertices. They can be nested.
5. A "split" vertex can split into any number of paths. The examples below only show 2 paths for each, but it could be more.

My challenge is the following: for each "split" vertex (any vertex that has at least 2 outgoing edges), find the vertices where its paths reconnect - if such a vertex exists. The solution should be as efficient as possible.

**Example A:**

[example a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgbAC.png)

In this example, vertex A is a "split" vertex, and its "reconnect vertex" is F.

**Example B:**

[example b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liumk.png)

Here, there are two split vertices: A and E. For both of them vertex G is the reconnect vertex.

**Example C:**

[example c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1T17.png)

Now there are three split vertices: A, D and E. The corresponding reconnect vertices are:

- A -> K
- D -> K
- E -> J

**Example D:**

[example d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX34K.png)

Here we have three split vertices again: A, D and E. But this time, vertex E doesn't have a reconnect vertex because one of the paths terminates early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is:

1. Connect each vertex with out-degree 0 to a single *terminal vertex*
2. Construct the [dominator tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)) of the edge-reversed graph.  The linked wikipedia article points to a couple algorithms for doing this.
3. The "reconnect vertex" for a split vertex is its immediate dominator in the edge-reversed graph, i.e., its parent in that dominator tree.  This is called its "postdominator" in your original graph.  If it's the terminal vertex that you added, then it doesn't have a reconnect vertex in your original graph.

Comment: Awesome! I tried it and looks like this is in fact producing the results I needed!
For future searchers, the networkx package in python has some great methods (and source code) for finding dominators, which I found helpful: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/algorithms/dominance.html#immediate_dominators

My codebase isn't in python, but their source code - and the linked reference [1] helped.

Comment: Actually, while the algorithm does produce postdominators as described, I don't think my "reconnect vertices" are postdominators as such.
For instance, here's example D again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mboqv.png
I consider anything in the red box being the "internals" of split A. I would consider K to be the reconnect vertex for A (and D, for that matter).

Technically K isn't the immediate postdominator though, because not all paths from A pass through it.
For my purposes, K should be a reconnect vertex, but I can't come up with a solid definition of how it relates to the graph structure

Comment: Your original example E seems to say the opposite.  Doesn't one of the paths "terminate early"?

Comment: Yes, vertex E doesn't have a reconnect vertex because one its paths terminates early. But for vertex A, vertex K is still a reconnect vertex, because the vertex A's right path eventually still reaches K.

Comment: I tried a modified version of your approach. In this version, I do not connect out-degree = 0 vertices to a terminal vertex.

For each out-degree=0 vertex, I run the dominator algorithm on a reversed graph. This gives me a couple of candidates for "reconnect vertices" for each split.

I then remove vertices with in-degree = 1 - in my scenario only vertices with multiple incoming edges can be rejoin vertices.

This leaves me with one or no rejoin vertex for each of my splits. I tried it on a couple of graphs and it seems to work, albeit less efficient than your original suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of identifying post-dominators in compilers and program analysis.  This is often used in the context of calculating control dependences in control flow graphs.  "Advanced Compiler Design and Implementation" is a good reference on these topics.

If the graph does not have cycles, then the solution (a) suggested by @matt-timmermans will work.

If the graph has cycles, then solution (a) can report spurious post-dominators.  In such cases, a network-flow based approach works better.  The algorithm to calculate non-termination sensitive control dependence in [this paper](https://rvprasad.bitbucket.io/publications/esop05.pdf) using this approach.  The basic idea is

1. at every split node, inject a unique token into the graph along each outgoing edge and
2. propagate the tokens thru the graph subject to this constraint: if node n is reachable from split node m, then tokens arriving at node m pass thru node n only if all tokens of node m have arrived at node n.

At the end, node n post-dominates node m if all tokens of node m have arrived at node n.

Comment: Thanks. My graphs don't have cycles, so Matt's answer is perfectly adequate. Thanks for your input though!